# How to get data controller to html file using variable in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, module

How to my post data is get controller file to html file. I have create email send extension in contact us form. But I have no idea how to store get data in controller to html file.

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$name = $data ['name'];
```

Comment: assuming that from some form means html file you are sending post to controller file, then why do you need post back in HTML? BTW you can use sessions.

Comment: I am send customer details in email. so i have customer details in controller to html file